# Why is NSPersistentStoreCoordinator not recognizing my managed object model?

Tags: core-data, ios8, nspersistentstore

I am trying to create a CoreData store with iCloud.  Following the example code in *iCloud Programming Guide for Core Data*, I have this piece of code:

```
    NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *coordinator = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel: salonbook.xcdatamodeld];
```

This is the image of my *managed object model*

[image]

I'm getting an error: Use of undeclared identifier 'salonbook'.

Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're getting the error because you're telling it to look for a variable named `salonbook`, which is not declared. You need to pass a reference to an `NSManagedObjectModel` instance here. Commonly that means you'd use `self.managedObjectModel`, but that really depends on the rest of your code. The steps need to be:

1. Create an `NSManagedObjectModel` instance from the model file
2. Create an `NSPersistentStoreCoordinator` using that model object.

Comment: Hi Tom... I'm sorry, but I can't figure out exactly *how* to create the NSManagedObjectModel from the model file... I've tried     NSManagedObjectModel *mom = [[NSManagedObjectModel alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:salonbook];  but that's not it.  Can you give me a sample? or a hint? or where I can find an example?  :D

Comment: Never mind... I figured it out... for those who have the same problem, here is how to create the NSManagedObjectModel based on the naming conventions I used above:

    NSString *modelPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"salonbook" ofType:@"momd"];
    NSURL *modelURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:modelPath];
    NSManagedObjectModel *managedObjectModel = [[NSManagedObjectModel alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:modelURL];